# Function to create standard normal distributed random variables (Box-Muller)

Tags: r, function

I would like to write a function that simulates an even number of standard normal distributed random variables (Usingt the Box-Muller transformation).
I am quite a beginner and tried to write the function below. At the moment I do not see how I can proceed to get it how I would like to have it.

My current code:

```
snorm <- function(){
  u1 <- runif(1)
  u2 <- runif(1)
  z1 <- ((((-2)*log(u1))^(1/2))*cos(2*u2*pi))
  z2 <- ((((-2)*log(u1))^(1/2))*sin(2*u2*pi))
  z <- list(z1,z2)
  return(z)
}
snorm()
```

Comment: Did you intend for the 3rd line to be `u2 <- runif(1) ` ?  Do that, and your function will return a pair of indep normal RVs.  What would you like to get?

Comment: OP: Even though it may seem obvious, it is worth saying *exactly* what is not working (i.e. in this case I'm guessing that you get an error `Error in snorm() : object 'u2' not found`), both to save answerers the trouble of cutting & pasting, and in case the problem is not replicable on other platforms.  But +1 for posting your (short!) code.  (My other comment is that I would think that the error message should have tipped you off to the problem which @CarlWitthoft has pointed out ... but maybe not?)

Comment: I ran your function 1000 times and got a very nice bell shaped distribution of results.  What else would you like the function to do?