# Generate random normal conditional on uniform distribution

Tags: r, distribution, normal-distribution

I have random variable X that is uniformly distributed over the interval [-1, 1]. I want to simulate in R the random variable Y conditional on X that is Gaussian.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821967/function-to-create-standard-normal-distributed-random-variables-box-muller) post that answers my questions but for the uniform distribution on the interval [0, 1] using Box-Muller method.

However, this does not work for the interval [-1, 0] because log of negative does not exist.

```
n <- 2000
X = runif(n, min = -1, max = 1)
Y = rnorm(n, 0, 1) # not conditional
```

Comment: I would ask this in CrossValidated to get a quicker and more complete conceptual response.

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between X and Y? How is Y conditional on X? Seems more like a fundamental misunderstanding of statistical distributions rather than a specific programming question. As such you should probably be asking for help at [stats.se], not Stack Overflow.

Comment: You need to state explicitly what you mean by conditioned on uniform distribution.  Box-Muller is probably not the way to go, because it generates pairs of normals from pairs of uniform inputs, so it's 2-2. You need a 1-1 correspondence for conditioning.